# HATEOAS in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, hateoas

I want to use express-hateoas-links package but it is not working:

> module "C:/Users/me/Documents/node/express-project/node_modules/express-hateoas-links/index"
> Could not find a declaration file for module 'express-hateoas-links'. 'C:/Users/me/Documents/node/express-project/node_modules/express-hateoas-links/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try `npm i --save-dev @types/express-hateoas-links` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'express-hateoas-links';`ts(7016)

```
import express, { json } from 'express';
import hateoasLinker from 'express-hateoas-links';

const friends = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'XXX'
  },
  ...
];

app.use(hateoasLinker);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`${req.method} ${req.url}`);
  next();
});

app.use(json());

app.get('/friends', (req, res) => {
  res.json(friends,[
    { rel: "self", method: "GET", href: 'http://localhost:3000/friends' },
    { rel: "create", method: "POST", title: 'Create Friends', href: 'http://localhost:3000/friends' }
  ]);
});
```

The application works but response does not contains links due to the error. ???

Comment: Not sure because I never used `express-hateoas-links`, but `friends` is an array, so you probably have to to loop over the array and add your hateoas links there, because the links should be on the single object and not on the array. The error just says you don't have types but types are only relevant during compile time, not during runtime

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. The problem is at the import. The package is written in js but the error message advises a d.ts file. I do not understand.

Comment: Have you tried to install the types? f there are no types add `//@ts-ignore` to the line, but again, that is only installing types which are used during compile time, this has nothing todo with runtime.. additionally I probably would not use that package at all, see [here] (https://snyk.io/advisor/npm-package/express-hateoas-links)

Comment: Thank you for help. I do it without any external package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember when I tried to use HATEAOS library can't use with an array JSON response, but I tried to use a map method

```
const response = catalogo.map(x => {
  return {
    name: x.name,
    description: x.description,
    href: {
      rel: "productos",
      method: "GET",
      href: 'http://localhost:8080/ver-productos/' + x._id
    },
  }
});

res.json({
  from,
  limit,
  total,
  response
});
```

This worked for me.